# What is header-onepage.php as opposed to header.php?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

After installing TheFox theme, I wanted to integrate Heap by adding some Javascript to the header.

However, there appears to be at least three related files:

[image]

I know that 'onepage' PHP files are pretty common with Wordpress themes, but I really don't understand there needs to be separate files.

What is the difference between `header.php` and `header-onepage.php`?

Also, if I decide to use plugins like [Header and Footer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer/) or [Insert Headers and Footers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/) would they insert the scripts into the right place? (i.e. `header-onepage`)?

Answer (score 0):

`header.php` is the standard WordPress template file for header stuff. When you use `get_header()`, WordPress automatically load `header.php`.

I am not sure but from name we can guess that `header-onepage.php` is loaded for one page template. `get_header('onepage')` will load `header-onepage.php`.

You can check standard WordPress template files here. https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files

Answer (score 0):

it depends what header template it's using the page on which you want to add Heap.
if it uses header.php then you need to add the Heap code on header.php